# Is there any way to save running configs of all routers in Cisco GNS3 simulation software

Tags: cisco

Suppose i have 8 routers in GNS3 toplogy. Now in order to save the config , i first need to do

```
copy run start
```

And then I have to save it in GNS.

Is there any option by which I save the running configs of all routers in start, rather than going at all routers individually?

Answer (score 1):

If the routers are accessible from the host you're running GNS on you should be able to use Kiwi CatTools to automate this.

http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-cattools-overview/